# Git permission denied public key

Tags: git, github

I followed the following link to get my github repo up [link]https://projects.raspberrypi.org/en/projects/getting-started-with-git/10[/link]. The setup worked. However when I try to do the initial push `git push origin master` I receive the following error

```
 permission denied publickey
 Fatal could not read from remote repository
 Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

It’s a public repo and I don’t know how to see if I have the correct permission. Not sure what username I am using. I never get asked for a username.

Comment: How did you create your repo?

Comment: Followed the steps in the link. `git init`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are acessing to the remote via ssh you have to upload your ssh public key to GitHub, you can find a how-to [here](https://help.github.com/articles/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/).

You can also use your github username/password if you access your repo through the HTTPS url.